# Rotate scrollpane over the X-axis in javafx - star wars like effect

Tags: java, javafx, user-controls, transform

I have a problem with a rotation of a usercontrol in javafx. My setup is as follows:

I have a scene with in the center a 400 by 600 scrollpanel called `scrollpane`, later populated dynamically with a vbox that contains a list of labels with text.

What I want to do is add a rotation on this panel to make it look like the starwars introduction text. I've managed to get the animation that scrolls through the text working, but when trying to rotate the panel over the X_AXIS it won't do as I want.

Goal: [Panel that is rotated as if it was this text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj7hX.jpg)

Currently [My best attempt after spending hours transforming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnBZw.png):

```
scrollpane.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(50, 300, 200, 20, Rotate.X_AXIS));
```

As you can see the text is aimed at the proper angle, but the control itself is not actually 3d rotated over the X-axis.
What do I need to add in order to go from what I currently have to the desired effect?
(That the top of the panel in absolute pixels is less wide compared to the bottom).

Comment: Here you need two properties, an italic format and the zoom, the closer the text is to the top of your `ScrollPane` the smaller it gets and the closer it gets to the lower part the bigger it gets.

Comment: Maybe applying a perspective transform effect would work: [PerspectiveTransform](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/PerspectiveTransform.html)

Comment: Probably you haven't set a camera...? Hard to know why it doesn't work without a complete example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've rotated it backwards; probably you're not seeing the rotation because you have something else wrong in your code.

This works for me:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StarWarsScrollPane extends Application {

    private final String text = "It is a period of civil war. Rebel spaceships, "
            + "striking from a hidden base, have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire."
            + " During the battle, Rebel spies managed to steal secret plans to the Empire's ultimate weapon,"
            + " the DEATH STAR, an armored space station with enough power to destroy an entire planet."
            + " Pursued by the Empire's sinister agents, Princess Leia races home aboard her starship,"
            + " custodian of the stolen plans that can save her people and restore freedom to the galaxy....";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label(text);
        label.setWrapText(true);
        label.setFont(Font.font(18));
        ScrollPane crawler = new ScrollPane(label);
        crawler.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        crawler.setFitToWidth(true);

        crawler.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(-50, 300, 200, 20, Rotate.X_AXIS));


        Scene scene = new Scene(crawler, 400, 400);
        scene.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera());


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Note that if you really want a scrolling "crawl" of text, you don't really need a scroll pane, but you can just use a text node and translate it in an animation. If you do this, be sure to add the translation *after* you add the rotation: transforms are applied in reverse order (as though you are right-multiplying the affine transformation matrices).

Here's an example of this ;)

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.DepthTest;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class StarWarsCrawler extends Application {

    private final String text = "It is a period of civil war. Rebel spaceships, "
            + "striking from a hidden base, have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire.\n\n"
            + "During the battle, Rebel spies managed to steal secret plans to the Empire's ultimate weapon,"
            + " the DEATH STAR, an armored space station with enough power to destroy an entire planet.\n\n"
            + "Pursued by the Empire's sinister agents, Princess Leia races home aboard her starship,"
            + " custodian of the stolen plans that can save her people and restore freedom to the galaxy....";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        int width = (int) primaryScreenBounds.getWidth() ;
        int height = (int) primaryScreenBounds.getHeight() ;

        Text textNode = createText(width);

        Translate translate = new Translate();
        textNode.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(-60, 300, height/2, height/30, Rotate.X_AXIS));
        textNode.getTransforms().add(translate);

        Timeline animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(45), new KeyValue(translate.yProperty(), -10*height))
        );
        textNode.setTranslateY(2*height);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        generateStarField(width, height, root);

        root.getChildren().add(textNode);

        Scene scene = createScene(root);

        primaryStage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        animation.play();
        animation.setOnFinished(e -> Platform.exit());
    }

    private Scene createScene(StackPane root) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.BLACK);
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
        camera.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        scene.setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
        scene.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if (e.getClickCount() ==2) {
                Platform.exit();
            }
        });
        return scene;
    }

    private Text createText(int width) {
        Text textNode = new Text(text);
        textNode.setWrappingWidth(width*1.25);
        textNode.setFont(Font.font("Franklin Gothic", width/12));
        textNode.setFill(Color.rgb(229, 177, 58));
        return textNode;
    }

    private void generateStarField(int width, int height, StackPane root) {
        int numStars = width * height / 900 ;

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= numStars ; i++) {
            double hue = rng.nextDouble() * 360 ;
            double saturation = rng.nextDouble() * 0.1 ;
            Color color = Color.hsb(hue, saturation, 1.0);
            Circle circle = new Circle(rng.nextInt(width), rng.nextInt(height), 2*rng.nextDouble(), color);
            circle.setManaged(false);
            circle.setTranslateZ(rng.nextDouble() * height * 1.25);
            root.getChildren().add(circle);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```